# What are the possible reasons why awk failed in the following scenario?

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I have used the following command in a shell script

```
awk '{print $0","}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

The result was that file2.txt is created but does not have `','` at the end of each line. And shell script execution was stopped at awk line. I don't see any reason why it failed. Can some one explain this behaviour of awk please?

Comment: It was not empty, the file2.txt has all the data from file1.txt but there is no ',' at the end of every line.

Comment: I am sorry, that was editing mistake. its actually `awk  '{print $0","}' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: Strange, command works for me. Try `sed 's/$/,/' file1.txt > file2.txt` for continuing your script.

Comment: The `awk` command also works for me.

Comment: How exactly does awk know that it is end of line? Because when I run this, its not adding a ',' at the end but its replacing the first character of every line with ','

Answer (score 2):

> ...its not adding a ',' at the end but its replacing the first character of every line with ','

You have DOS/Windows style line-endings (carriage return, line feed) in your file.  Consequently, `awk` is placing the comma *after* the carriage return but *before* the line feed.  Consider this file with DOS-line-endings:

```
$ cat file1.dos
line one
line two
line three
```

If we run the awk command, the result looks like:

```
$ awk '{print $0","}' file1.dos
,ine one
,ine two
,ine three
```

Use dos2unix or tr to remove the DOS line endings.  For example:

```
$ tr -d '\r' <file1.dos >file1
```

Now, it will work correctly:

```
$ awk '{print $0","}' file1
line one,
line two,
line three,
```

Comment: Thanks, Its exactly as you specified, the file was in windows format. It is resolved now.